# python - why do immutable objects not occupy same memory

Tags: python, immutability

*I'm using micropython but it shouldn't matter*

```
>>> b = [None]*40
>>> gc.collect(); gc.mem_free(); dir(); sys.modules
101
7008
['sys', '__name__', 'a', 'gc', 'b']
{}
>>> for i in range(40):
...     b[i] = (255, 0, 0)
...     gc.collect(); gc.mem_free();
...
...
...
5
6800
0
6768
0
6736
0
6704
0
6672
0
6640
0
6608
0
6576
0
6544
0
6512
0
6480
0
6448
0
6416
0
6384
0
6352
0
6320
0
6288
0
6256
0
6224
0
6192
0
6160
0
6128
0
6096
0
6064
0
6032
0
6000
0
5968
0
5936
0
5904
0
5872
0
5840
0
5808
0
5776
0
5744
0
5712
0
5680
0
5648
0
5616
0
5584
0
5552
>>>
```

*The small number is the number of objects `gc.collect()` collected and large number is how much free memory exists.*

`(255, 0, 0)` is a tuple which is immutable and it contains immutable objects so why does the amount of free memory decrease after each assignment?

If an object is immutable, what's the point of Python making copies of it?
Why not just assign the same "pointer" to each `b[i]`?

**UPDATE**

I used a bigger number in the tuple `(55555555555555555555, 55555555555555555555)` and the memory usage is the same.

```
    >>> gc.collect(); gc.mem_free(); dir(); sys.modules
5
6368
['sys', '__name__', 'gc', 'i']
{}
>>> b = [None]*40
>>> for i in range(40):
...     b[i] = (55555555555555555555,55555555555555555555)
...     id(b[i])
...     gc.collect(); gc.mem_free()
...
...
...
5347968
10
5824
5347136
0
5808
5347312
0
5792
5347456
0
5776
5347536
0
5760
5347552
0
5744
5347696
0
5728
5347712
0
5712
5347984
0
5696
5348176
0
5680
5348192
0
5664
5348208
0
5648
5348224
0
5632
5348240
0
5616
5348256
0
5600
5348272
0
5584
5348288
0
5568
5348608
0
5552
5348640
0
5536
5348656
0
5520
5348672
0
5504
5348688
0
5488
5348704
0
5472
5348720
0
5456
5348736
0
5440
5348848
0
5424
5348864
0
5408
5348880
0
5392
5348896
0
5376
5348912
0
5360
5348928
0
5344
5348944
0
5328
5349104
0
5312
5349120
0
5296
5349136
0
5280
5349152
0
5264
5349168
0
5248
5349184
0
5232
5349200
0
5216
5349216
0
5200
>>>
```

**But when I use the integer `(55555555555555555555)`, the memory usage does NOT change as I iterate.**

Comment: How can you be sure its *not* using pointers? (255,0,0) doesn't seem like it would be much different in size than a pointer to itself.

Comment: @Octopus because I already pre-allocated the list of size 40 which would point to the `None` object aka `const mp_obj_none_t mp_const_none_obj = {{&mp_type_NoneType}};`

Comment: It takes time and memory to track which objects that *could* be reused are available for reuse. The overhead generally isn't worth it compared to just creating new copies.

Comment: In order for immutable objects to share memory, it would be necessary for Python to recognize that an object that would be created is identical to an existing object.  In the worst case, this would require examining *every existing object of the same type* to see if there's a duplicate.  Python does do this in specific cases where duplicates are likely and easily detected (small integers, in particular), but I believe the only deduplication in the case of tuples is that there is only ever a single empty tuple.  (No idea if Micropython does things the same way.)

Comment: CPython keeps a small, *fixed* set of integers in memory for reuse; there is no comparable set of tuples that one would expect to be common enough to be worth tracking.

Comment: @chepner I understand that but does that mean it's NEVER done? But you've brought up a good point: micropython - and probably CPython - optimizes integer storage. Maybe `(255,  0, 0)` doesn't cross the threshold for reusing. I'm gonna store a huuuge number and retry.

Comment: Does micropython support `id()`? If so compare e.g. `id(b[0])` and `id(b[1])` to check for identity.

Comment: @Adrian: Note that at least in the CPython reference interpreter, if this code was packaged up in a function, `(255, 0, 0)` would be cached in the function constants. Sure, it wouldn't be the same `(255, 0, 0)` used in some *other* function (which would require the absurd search mentioned by @jasonharper, or a complicated interning protocol), but it does in fact construct the `tuple` once and reuse it in functions. Global scope can't do that because there is no concept of an array of global constants, and adding one wasn't considered important enough to justify the code/maintenance.

Comment: @Adrian: `(55555555555555555555)` is not a `tuple`. It's a plain `int` with superfluous grouping parentheses around it. If you want a one-element `tuple`, you'd need to add a trailing comma: `(55555555555555555555,)`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I updated it and it's the same behavior.

Comment: Related: see how long it takes you to run `((((((((((1,)*10,)*10,)*10,)*10,)*10,)*10,)*10,)*10,)*10,)*10`, which should only construct a very small number of tuples with a lot of shared items. On CPython, you'll find it takes ages, because the hashing involved in the constant folding and deduplication gets incredibly expensive. (IIRC, they decided the issue was unlikely to come up in practice and decided not to do anything about it.) It's an extreme case with a few other factors involved, but it's a good demonstration that constant deduplication isn't free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because generalized interning of *all* immutable objects in the interpreter is complicated, and adds a ton of code that rarely saves anything worthwhile.

That said, your code *does* use a single copy of the `tuple` on the CPython reference interpreter. It's an implementation detail, so each interpreter can make its own decisions here, and I guess Micropython didn't choose to do it (possibly to keep the interpreter simple enough to run on weaker hardware).

It looks like Micropython performs caching for `int` constants, but not for `tuple`s; `tuple`s are harder to handle (at least initially, CPython didn't do this in the main AST phase, it just ran a peephole optimizer over the resulting byte code to convert runs of `LOAD_CONST` followed by a `BUILD_TUPLE` using only `LOAD_CONST` results to a `LOAD_CONST` of the resulting `tuple`), and the extra work involved may have been deemed not worthwhile.

Comment: But when I used the int `(55555555555555555555)` the memory usage did NOT increase. Is it only for certain immutable objects?

Comment: @Adrian: It's possible Micropython makes some efforts at caching `int` constants, but not `tuple` constants. CPython has a small `int` cache that is used everywhere, but only covers `int`s from (implementation detail) `-5` to `256` (inclusive). It does cache larger values in the function's array of constants, but that's only for constants (where the small `int` cache covers all uses of `int`, even dynamically computed values), and it's not a global cache. You're off in "implementation detail" territory; there is no one answer.

Comment: CPython would reuse the same tuple even in the interactive case demonstrated in the question. The behavior in the question is specific to MicroPython (which I don't have installed and am not an expert in, so I can't say much more than that).

Comment: @user2357112: Yeah, I was just testing that. CPython, it does in fact cache the constant even at global scope; for both global and function scope it looks to be a per-use cache though (so `print(id((255, 0, 0), id((255, 0, 0))` shows two independent copies). It's a little hard to inspect the `__main__` module with `dis`, so I think solving this would involve direct C source code checks, which hardly seems worth it when the OP wants details of Micropython. I updated the answer to remove the unsubstantiated claim.